# Sorting object attributes in different orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm writing a soccer league program and I want to sort the table before printing it out. Each team is a member of a class with certain attributes and so far I've been able to sort the integer attributes correctly.

```
for team in sorted(teams, key=attrgetter("points", "goalDiff", "scored", "name"), reverse = True):
```

I want all the attributes except `name` to be reversed, is there a possible way to "un-reverse" the `name` attribute in this line of code or do I have to take on a different approach?

Comment: Are the other values numbers?

Comment: Yes, all attributes except "name" are integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all attributes (except the name) are numeric, negate those numbers to get a reverse sort for those:

```
sorted(teams, key=lambda t: (-t.points, -t.goalDiff, -t.scored, t.name))
```

Negating numbers gives you a way to reverse their sort order without actually having to reverse the sort.

If that's not the case, then you'd have to sort twice, first just by the `name` attribute (in forward order), then in reverse order by the other attributes. For any object where `points`, `goalDiff` and `scored` are equal, the original sorting order (by name) is retained, because the sort algorithm Python uses is stable:

```
sorted(
    sorted(teams,  key=attrgetter('name')),
    key=attrgetter("points", "goalDiff", "scored"),
    reverse=True)
```